# Problems reading in Pipe delimited csv with special characters into R

Tags: r, csv, data-import

I've been trying to read in a pipe delimited [csv](/questions/tagged/csv) file containing 96 variables about some volunteer water quality data. Randomly within the file, there's single and double quotation marks as well as semi-colons, dashes, slashes, and likely other special characters

Name: Jonathan "Joe" Smith; Jerry; Emily; etc.

From the output of several variables (such as `IsNewVolunteer`), it seems that [r](/questions/tagged/r) is having issues reading in the data. `IsNewVolunteer` should always be `Y` or `N`, but numbers are appearing and when I queried those lines it appears that the data is getting shifted. Variables that are clearly not names are in the `Firstname` and `lastname` column.

[image: Shifted data columns]

The original data format makes it a little difficult to see and troubleshoot, especially due to extra variables. I would find a way to remove them, but the goal of the work with `R` is to provide code that will be able to run on a dataset that is frequently updated.

[image: Original Dataset]

I've tried

```
read.table("dnrvisualstream.csv",sep="|",stringsAsFactors = FALSE,quote="")
```

But that produces the following error:

> Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
>     line 132 did not have 94 elements

However, there's nothing out of the ordinary that I've noticed about line 132. I've had more success with

```
read.csv("dnrvisualstream.csv",sep="|",stringsAsFactors = FALSE,quote="")
```

but that still produces offsets and errors as discussed above. Is there something I'm doing incorrectly? Any information would be helpful.

Comment: Please take a look at [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), to modify your question, with a smaller sample taken from your data (check `?dput()`). Posting images of your data or no data makes it difficult to impossible for us to help you!

Comment: Have you tried specifying the encoding? Something like: `read.csv("dnrvisualstream.csv",sep="|",stringsAsFactors = FALSE,quote="", encoding = "UTF-8")`. You also have multiple `||||` separators in rows 2,3,4, and 21,22 that are visible in your screenshot. You might need to edit your .csv either in R or manually to strip some of them out.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's one of two issues:

**Encoding is either UTF-8 or UTF-16:**

Try this...

```
read.csv("dnrvisualstream.csv", sep = "|", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, quote = "", encoding = UTF-8)
```

or this...

```
read.csv("dnrvisualstream.csv", sep = "|", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, quote = "", encoding = UTF-16)
```

**Too many separators:**

If this doesn't work, right-click on your .csv file and open it in a text editor. You have multiple `||||` separators in rows 2,3,4, and 21,22 that are visible in your screenshot. Press `CTRL+H` to find and replace:

```
Find: ||||
Replace: |
```

Save the new file and try to open in R again.